# Do tasks within a Celery chord always execute in order?

Tags: python, redis, celery

Are tasks within a celery chord guaranteed to execute in the order that they were started?
I repeated this example many times and the order was identical. From the docs, I interpreted that the tasks will occur concurrently and so the order would be unpredictable.
I added a `time.sleep(random())` and the result still remained `True`.

```
# pip install celery
# docker run -d -p 6379:6379 redis

# app.py
import time
import random
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379')

app.conf.update(
    result_backend='redis://localhost:6379/0',
)
@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@app.task()
def check_task_order(numbers):
    time.sleep(random.random())
    return numbers == sorted(numbers)

# start.py
from celery import chord
from app import add, tsum


print(chord(
    add.subtask((i, i)) for i in range(100)
)(tsum.subtask()).get())


# terminal 1:
celery -A app worker --loglevel=info

# terminal 2
python start.py
>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

The task execution order is not guaranteed as they are asynchronous. However, the return values are in the order that the tasks were given.

To prove this, I updated the task definitions and found that `tsum` was now returning False instead of true. Note that I also increased the task count from 100 to 1000.

```
@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return (x, time.time()) # Return the task number and current time

@app.task()
def tsum(numbers):
    time.sleep(random.random())
    # If the task return values sorted on the task number differs from the
    #   task return values sorted on the time they executed,
    #   we know that the execution order differs from the return order.
    return (
        numbers == sorted(numbers) and 
        numbers == sorted(numbers, key=lambda x: x[1])
    )
```